# Keras está usando todo o batch de uma vez no fit_generator em um modelo com 3 saídas

Tags: python-3.x, redes-neurais, keras

Bom dia,

Estou usando o modelo disponível nesse Git [GoogleNet in Keras](https://gist.github.com/joelouismarino/a2ede9ab3928f999575423b9887abd14) para transfer learning e estou tentando adaptar o fit_generator do Keras para uso no modelo. Como pode ser visto no link, há 3 saídas do modelo. Essas saídas são, individualmente, idênticas uma a outra mas preciso passar as 3 para dar certo. 
Exemplo: [y,y,y] para uma entrada de x.

A entrada está certa, não há nenhum problema. O problema é que na saída o keras está tentando usar um *batch* inteiro para cada entrada. Com um *batch* igual a 32, apareceu a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected new_loss1_classifier_act to have shape (1681,) but got array with shape (32,)
```

aonde 1681 é o número de labels codificados que cada saída recebe.

Primeiro, eu modifiquei a classe BatchFromFilesMixin, para entregar uma lista de 3 saídas ao invés de uma:

```
import os
import threading
import numpy as np
from keras_preprocessing import get_keras_submodule

try:
    IteratorType = get_keras_submodule('utils').Sequence
except ImportError:
    IteratorType = object

from keras_preprocessing.image.utils import (array_to_img,
                    img_to_array,
                    load_img)

class GoogleNet_BatchFromFilesMixin():
    """Adds methods related to getting batches from filenames
    It includes the logic to transform image files to batches.
    """

    def set_processing_attrs(self,
                             image_data_generator,
                             target_size,
                             color_mode,
                             data_format,
                             save_to_dir,
                             save_prefix,
                             save_format,
                             subset,
                             interpolation):

        self.image_data_generator = image_data_generator
        self.target_size = tuple(target_size)
        if color_mode not in {'rgb', 'rgba', 'grayscale'}:
            raise ValueError('Invalid color mode:', color_mode,
                             '; expected "rgb", "rgba", or "grayscale".')
        self.color_mode = color_mode
        self.data_format = data_format
        if self.color_mode == 'rgba':
            if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
                self.image_shape = self.target_size + (4,)
            else:
                self.image_shape = (4,) + self.target_size
        elif self.color_mode == 'rgb':
            if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
                self.image_shape = self.target_size + (3,)
            else:
                self.image_shape = (3,) + self.target_size
        else:
            if self.data_format == 'channels_last':
                self.image_shape = self.target_size + (1,)
            else:
                self.image_shape = (1,) + self.target_size

        self.save_to_dir = save_to_dir
        self.save_prefix = save_prefix
        self.save_format = save_format
        self.interpolation = interpolation
        if subset is not None:
            validation_split = self.image_data_generator._validation_split
            if subset == 'validation':
                split = (0, validation_split)
            elif subset == 'training':
                split = (validation_split, 1)
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    'Invalid subset name: %s;'
                    'expected "training" or "validation"' % (subset,))
        else:
            split = None
        self.split = split
        self.subset = subset

    def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):
        """Gets a batch of transformed samples.
        # Arguments
            index_array: Array of sample indices to include in batch.
        # Returns
            A batch of transformed samples.
        """
        batch_x = np.zeros((len(index_array),) + self.image_shape, dtype=self.dtype)
        # build batch of image data
        # self.filepaths is dynamic, is better to call it once outside the loop
        filepaths = self.filepaths
        for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
            img = load_img(filepaths[j],
                           color_mode=self.color_mode,
                           target_size=self.target_size,
                           interpolation=self.interpolation)
            x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
            # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,
            # but not PIL images.
            if hasattr(img, 'close'):
                img.close()
            if self.image_data_generator:
                params = self.image_data_generator.get_random_transform(x.shape)
                x = self.image_data_generator.apply_transform(x, params)
                x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)
            batch_x[i] = x
        # optionally save augmented images to disk for debugging purposes
        if self.save_to_dir:
            for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
                img = array_to_img(batch_x[i], self.data_format, scale=True)
                fname = '{prefix}_{index}_{hash}.{format}'.format(
                    prefix=self.save_prefix,
                    index=j,
                    hash=np.random.randint(1e7),
                    format=self.save_format)
                img.save(os.path.join(self.save_to_dir, fname))
        # build batch of labels
        if self.class_mode == 'input':
            batch_y = batch_x.copy()
        elif self.class_mode in {'binary', 'sparse'}:
            batch_y = np.empty(len(batch_x), dtype=self.dtype)
            for i, n_observation in enumerate(index_array):
                batch_y[i] = self.classes[n_observation]
        elif self.class_mode == 'categorical':
            batch_y = np.zeros((len(batch_x), len(self.class_indices)),
                               dtype=self.dtype)
            for i, n_observation in enumerate(index_array):
                batch_y[i, self.classes[n_observation]] = 1.
        elif self.class_mode == 'multi_output':
            batch_y = [output[index_array] for output in self.labels]

        elif self.class_mode == 'raw':
            batch_y = self.labels[index_array]
        else:
            return batch_x
        if self.sample_weight is None:
            #MODIFICADO
            return batch_x, [batch_y, batch_y, batch_y]
        else:
            #MODIFICADO
            return batch_x, [batch_y, batch_y, batch_y], self.sample_weight[index_array]

    @property
    def filepaths(self):
        """List of absolute paths to image files"""
        raise NotImplementedError(
            '`filepaths` property method has not been implemented in {}.'
            .format(type(self).__name__)
        )

    @property
    def labels(self):
        """Class labels of every observation"""
        raise NotImplementedError(
            '`labels` property method has not been implemented in {}.'
            .format(type(self).__name__)
        )

    @property
    def sample_weight(self):
        raise NotImplementedError(
            '`sample_weight` property method has not been implemented in {}.'
            .format(type(self).__name__)
        )
```

Aonde eu modifiquei, está com a *hashtag* 'MODIFICADO'.

Em seguida, eu modifiquei a classe DataFrameIterator. Não mudei nada no corpo do código, só reescrevi ela para herdar o novo BatchFromFilesMixIn, que agora se chama GoogleNet_BatchFromFilesMixIn:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import warnings

import numpy as np

from keras_preprocessing.image.iterator import Iterator
from keras_preprocessing.image.utils import validate_filename

class GoogleNet_DataFrameIterator(GoogleNet_BatchFromFilesMixin, Iterator):
...
    super(GoogleNet_DataFrameIterator, self).set_processing_attrs(image_data_generator,
                                                        target_size,
                                                        color_mode,
                                                        data_format,
                                                        save_to_dir,
                                                        save_prefix,
                                                        save_format,
                                                        subset,
                                                        interpolation)
...
super(GoogleNet_DataFrameIterator, self).__init__(self.samples,
                                                batch_size,
                                                shuffle,
                                                seed)
```

E finalmente criei uma classe herdada da ImageDataGenerator, modificando apenas o método flow_from_dataframe, para utilizar a recém-criada classe

```
GoogleNet_DataFrameIterator.
class GoogleNet_ImageDataGenerator(ImageDataGenerator):
    def flow_from_dataframe(self,
                            dataframe,
                            directory=None,
                            x_col="filename",
                            y_col="class",
                            weight_col=None,
                            target_size=(256, 256),
                            color_mode='rgb',
                            classes=None,
                            class_mode='categorical',
                            batch_size=32,
                            shuffle=True,
                            seed=None,
                            save_to_dir=None,
                            save_prefix='',
                            save_format='png',
                            subset=None,
                            interpolation='nearest',
                            validate_filenames=True,
                            **kwargs):
...

    return GoogleNet_DataFrameIterator(
                dataframe,
                directory,
                self,
                x_col=x_col,
                y_col=y_col,
                weight_col=weight_col,
                target_size=target_size,
                color_mode=color_mode,
                classes=classes,
                class_mode=class_mode,
                data_format=self.data_format,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                shuffle=shuffle,
                seed=seed,
                save_to_dir=save_to_dir,
                save_prefix=save_prefix,
                save_format=save_format,
                subset=subset,
                interpolation=interpolation,
                validate_filenames=validate_filenames
            )
```

Então criei as instâncias e etc... O dataframe já está no formato certo e etc, o problema está no Keras passando um batch inteiro de uma vez, como disse antes.

```
train_datagen = GoogleNet_ImageDataGenerator(data_format = 'channels_first')
test_datagen = GoogleNet_ImageDataGenerator(data_format = 'channels_first')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=train,
            directory='img',
            x_col="filename",
            y_col=categories,
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='multi_output')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=validate,
        directory='img',
        x_col="filename",
        y_col=categories,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode='multi_output')

from keras.optimizers import SGD

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.fit_generator(
    generator = train_generator,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Se eu mudo o batch de treino para 64, aparece:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected new_loss1_classifier_act to have shape (1681,) but got array with shape (64,)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar o erro, ou é um bug do próprio Keras?

Versões usadas:
Python 3.7
Keras 2.3.1

Comment: Se o problema foi resolvido você poderia [edit] sua pergunta para remover a solução, criar a sua resposta com sua solução e depois marcá-la como aceita. Veja: [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Obrigado, Fernando! Sou novo por aqui, não sabia disso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvido**

Troquei o seguinte código do GoogleNet_BatchFromFilesMixin():

```
elif self.class_mode == 'raw':
                batch_y = self.labels[index_array]
```

para

```
elif self.class_mode == 'raw':
                batch_y = [self.labels[index_array],self.labels[index_array],self.labels[index_array]]
```

e troquei o argumento método flow_from_dataframe de class_mode = 'multi_output' para class_mode = 'raw'. Também voltei o trecho de código

```
if self.sample_weight is None:
    #MODIFICADO
    return batch_x, [batch_y, batch_y, batch_y]
```

para o original:

```
if self.sample_weight is None:
    return batch_x, batch_y
```